# How to build yaml-cpp on Visual Studio/cmake by command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, yaml, yaml-cpp

I built [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) with `vs.bat cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ../`:

```
$ vs.bat cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ../
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
-- Check for working C compiler: F:/VisualStudio2015/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: F:/VisualStudio2015/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: F:/VisualStudio2015/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: F:/VisualStudio2015/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: D:/Evandro/Documentos/Cygwin64/bin/python (found version "1.4")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs
```

Where `vs.bat` is:

```
@echo off

:: Path to your Visual Studio folder.
::
:: Examples:
::     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
::     F:\VisualStudio2015
set VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER=F:\VisualStudio2015

:: Load compilation environment
call "%VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER%\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64

:: Invoke compiler with any options passed to this batch file
%*
```

After genereating the project for Visual Studio, I ran `vs.bat devenv YAML_CPP.sln /Build`:

```
$ vs.bat devenv YAML_CPP.sln /Build
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.24720.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/gmock-1.7.0/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>------ Build started: Project: gmock, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: gtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: yaml-cpp static md, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: gmock_main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/test/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/CMakeLists.txt
3>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
3>  gtest-all.cc
2>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/test/gmock-1.7.0/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/gmock-1.7.0/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
4>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/CMakeLists.txt
5>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/test/gmock-1.7.0/CMakeLists.txt
4>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  gtest-all.cc
5>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/gmock-1.7.0/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
5>  gtest-all.cc
4>  binary.cpp
4>  convert.cpp
4>  directives.cpp
2>  gmock-all.cc
5>  gmock-all.cc
3>  gtest.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\test\gmock-1.7.0\gtest\Debug\libgtest.lib
6>------ Build started: Project: gtest_main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>  emit.cpp
6>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/test/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/CMakeLists.txt
6>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
4>  emitfromevents.cpp
5>  gmock_main.cc
4>  emitter.cpp
6>  gtest_main.cc
2>  Generating Code...
2>  gmock.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\test\gmock-1.7.0\Debug\libgmock.lib
7>------ Skipped Build: Project: RUN_TESTS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
8>------ Skipped Build: Project: format, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
6>  gtest_main.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\test\gmock-1.7.0\gtest\Debug\libgtest_main.lib
4>  emitterstate.cpp
5>  Generating Code...
4>  emitterutils.cpp
5>  gmock_main.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\test\gmock-1.7.0\Debug\libgmock_main.lib
4>  exceptions.cpp
4>  exp.cpp
4>  memory.cpp
4>  node.cpp
4>  node_data.cpp
4>  nodebuilder.cpp
4>  nodeevents.cpp
4>  null.cpp
4>  ostream_wrapper.cpp
4>  parse.cpp
4>  parser.cpp
4>  regex_yaml.cpp
4>  Generating Code...
4>  Compiling...
4>  scanner.cpp
4>  scanscalar.cpp
4>  scantag.cpp
4>  scantoken.cpp
4>  simplekey.cpp
4>  singledocparser.cpp
4>  stream.cpp
4>  tag.cpp
4>  graphbuilder.cpp
4>  graphbuilderadapter.cpp
4>  Generating Code...
4>  yaml-cpp.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\Debug\libyaml-cppmdd.lib
9>------ Build started: Project: parse, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
10>------ Build started: Project: read, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
11>------ Build started: Project: run-tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
12>------ Build started: Project: sandbox, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
9>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/util/CMakeLists.txt
12>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/util/CMakeLists.txt
10>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/util/CMakeLists.txt
9>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
12>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
10>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
9>  parse.cpp
12>  sandbox.cpp
10>  read.cpp
11>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/test/CMakeLists.txt
11>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
11>  main.cpp
11>  ostream_wrapper_test.cpp
12>  sandbox.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\util\Debug\sandbox.exe
12>  sandbox.vcxproj -> D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/Debug/sandbox.pdb (Full PDB)
10>  read.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\util\Debug\read.exe
10>  read.vcxproj -> D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/Debug/read.pdb (Full PDB)
9>  parse.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\util\Debug\parse.exe
9>  parse.vcxproj -> D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/util/Debug/parse.pdb (Full PDB)
11>  regex_test.cpp
11>  emitter_test.cpp
11>  encoding_test.cpp
11>  gen_emitter_test.cpp
11>  handler_spec_test.cpp
11>  handler_test.cpp
11>  load_node_test.cpp
11>  node_spec_test.cpp
11>  node_test.cpp
11>  Generating Code...
11>  run-tests.vcxproj -> D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\yaml-cpp\bin_msvs\test\Debug\run-tests.exe
11>  run-tests.vcxproj -> D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/test/Debug/run-tests.pdb (Full PDB)
13>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
13>  Building Custom Rule D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/CMakeLists.txt
13>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
14>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
14>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
========== Build: 11 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 3 skipped ==========
```

Now I am trying to link it with my project test file called `main.cpp`:

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main( int argumentsCount, char* argumentsStringList[] )
{
    std::cout << "YAML\n" << std::endl;

    // https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/
    YAML::Node SyntaxFile = YAML::LoadFile("test.beauty-blocks");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I try to compile it with `vs.bat cl.exe /I. /I./libraries/yaml-cpp/include libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Debug/libyaml-cppmdd.lib /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp` is does outputs:

```
$ vs.bat cl.exe /I. /I./libraries/yaml-cpp/include libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Debug/libyaml-cppmdd.lib /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Debug/libyaml-cppmdd.lib
main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(parse.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(parse.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(exceptions.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(exceptions.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(parser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(parser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(nodebuilder.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(nodebuilder.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(directives.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(directives.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanner.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanner.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(singledocparser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(singledocparser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(node_data.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(node_data.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(memory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(memory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(regex_yaml.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(regex_yaml.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(simplekey.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(simplekey.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scantoken.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scantoken.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(tag.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(tag.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(null.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(null.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanscalar.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanscalar.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scantag.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scantag.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(exp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(exp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ) already defined in libcpmt.lib(uncaught.obj)
...
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(exp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scantoken.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(tag.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanscalar.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??$?6DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@@Z)
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scantag.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(memory.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(regex_yaml.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(stream.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(simplekey.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(directives.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanner.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(singledocparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
...
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(parse.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(exceptions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(parser.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(nodebuilder.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(tag.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(nodebuilder.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(scanner.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(singledocparser.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
libyaml-cppmdd.lib(node_data.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
MSVCRTD.lib(_chandler4gs_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Moreoever I searched for the error `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for` and I found out this question:

1. [error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668200/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-iterator-debug-level-value-0-doesnt)

It is saying I am compiling one project with `debug mode`,
but I could not find out how to configure it to build both
on `release mode` or in `debug mode`.

---

**Resumely** these are the command lines used:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ../
devenv YAML_CPP.sln /Build
cl.exe /I. /I./libraries/yaml-cpp/include libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Debug/libyaml-cppmdd.lib /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp
```

How would be to put them to release or debug mode?

The `yaml-cpp` documentation does not mention how to do it. I tried to use this other answer:

1. [Debug vs Release in CMAKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake)

But when I ran `vs.bat cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ../` outputting:

```
$ vs.bat cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ../
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE


-- Build files have been written to: D:/source/libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs
```

It seems not to be recognizing the mentioned variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` on that answer. Was also opened an issue on: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/483

---

## Update

Even after the [@flyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347964)'s answer I got a new error:

```
./cl_env.bat /I. /I./libraries/yaml-cpp/include libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Release/libyaml-cppmd.lib /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Release/libyaml-cppmd.lib
main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(exceptions.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(memory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(node_data.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(parse.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(parser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(nodebuilder.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
libyaml-cppmd.lib(directives.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
...
libyaml-cppmd.lib(nodebuilder.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(directives.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(scanner.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(exceptions.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported in function "void __cdecl std::_Deallocate(void *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_Deallocate@std@@YAXPAXII@Z)
libyaml-cppmd.lib(memory.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(node_data.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(parse.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(scanscalar.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_destroy imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(scantag.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_destroy imported
...
libyaml-cppmd.lib(singledocparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_copy imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(scantoken.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_copy imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(tag.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_copy imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(scanscalar.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_copy imported
libyaml-cppmd.lib(node_data.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_copy imported in function "public: __thiscall YAML::Exception::Exception(struct YAML::Mark const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Exception@YAML@@QAE@ABUMark@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
libyaml-cppmd.lib(parse.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ___std_exception_copy imported in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall std::basic_filebuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_G?$basic_filebuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEPAXI@Z)
...
libyaml-cppmd.lib(parse.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __errno imported in function _memcpy_s
libyaml-cppmd.lib(scanscalar.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _memchr imported in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::find_last_not_of(char const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)const " (?find_last_not_of@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEIPBDII@Z)
MSVCRT.lib(_chandler4gs_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

But after I searched `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease'`, I found out [LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in file.obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887001/lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-runtimelibrary-value-mt-staticrelease-doesn), therefore I added `/MD` ([desc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)) to my `main`'s the command line, resulting on this full version steps:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ../
devenv YAML_CPP.sln /Build Release
cl.exe /I. /I./libraries/yaml-cpp/include libraries/yaml-cpp/bin_msvs/Debug/libyaml-cppmdd.lib /EHsc /MD /Femain.exe main.cpp
```

Now it is finally compiling fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is a CMake target which allows multiple configurations (you can have both a *Debug*, a *Release* and several other build configurations in a Visual Studio project). Therefore, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is ignored when generating the `*.sln` file.

Instead, you should give the configuration when invoking the compiler, i.e.

```
vs.bat devenv YAML_CPP.sln /build Debug
```

or

```
vs.bat devenv YAML_CPP.sln /build Release
```

It seems strange that your command even works given that the configuration name is not optional according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx).

Since you compile your `main.cpp` without debug options, you should compile yaml-cpp with `Release` configuration.

In general, it would be a good idea to generate a Solution file for your code with CMAKE – you can then include the yaml-cpp CMAKE file and are guaranteed that everything compiles with the same switches.