# Project compile with MDd even when setting to MTd

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, microsoft-runtime-library

I'm trying to compile an exe that depends on some other static projects.
Some of the projects depends on OpenCV libraries that compiled with `MTd` runtime library option.
What I did is to set the runtime library of all my projects to `MTd` (in the runtime library option on visual studio project's properties) as well. When I compile only the static projects everything going well, but when I compile the exe file I get an error like this:

`Transform_Static.lib (Transform.obj  : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'Runtime Library' value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' dosen't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in Math_UT.obj`

I tried to add/remove libs from the linker dependencies of the exe project but nothing change, what else can I do?
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT\_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD\_DynamicRelease' in file.obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887001/lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-runtimelibrary-value-mt-staticrelease-doesn)

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the active build configuration? It's very easy in visual studio to modify the wrong configuration

Comment: @brc-dd This the same problem but after tried all the options that suggested there I'm still on the same situation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes I double checked that.

Answer (score 0):

First, You could check if `Runtime Library` is `MTd`.

Then, you could clean the project and rebuild the project.

Also, you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [LNK2038](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2038?view=vs-2019) and the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714877/mismatch-detected-for-runtimelibrary).